# Background-color on text elements

Tags: html, css, text, background-color

Can anyone help me out with background-color on some text.

I would like the background color to have about 40-50% of the text's height and to follow up the rest of the text if the text breaks up into another row. Any ideas?

I have tried to play around with the `:before` and `:after` selectors, but I unfortunately did not get the result I wanted.

I have also tried to use span within h1 tag, giving it background color and specific height, but nothing aswell.
Any ideas on this one?

I want background color to have about 40-50% of the text's height

I want to achieve essentially this:

[image: Example of what i want to achieve]

Comment: I suggest you check someone's answer as an accepted answer (you get 2 free rep and visitors will be able to find their answer easier), I've deleted my previous answer because I believe you have got a correct answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i have read your question correctly, however you want a text tag to have a background color you could always put the background on the parent element or use padding on the text tag.

```
<h1 style="padding: 2em; background: red;">Sample Text</h1>
```

Or

```
<div style="padding: 2em; background: red;">
 <p>Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Edit: The below is what you're looking for.

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.half-highlight {
  font-size: 30px;
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, green 50%);
  background-origin: 0;
  background-size: 200% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}

.half-highlight {
  background-position: -100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="half-highlight">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae, error tenetur, nihil tempore illum nulla aliquid debitis nostrum sequi harum possimus commodi unde iusto rerum temporibus? Consequatur porro cumque similique.
  </span>
</div>

<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry it is not, look Akshay Bawane's aswer. Thats the effect i want.

Comment: Yes it is, thank you so much. Sorry for delayed answer i was busy these days. Thank's again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Apply this css may be this will work for you.

```
 p {
    border: none;
    color: #000;
    width: auto;
    height: 48px;
    font-size: 32px;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
p:before{
    content: '';
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    height: 40%;
    background: #ff00006e;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Html goes here...

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Where are you coming up with a button in all this? I know the question is thoroughly off topic--it will be deleted eventually--but i presume  you are guessing at all this and SO is not about guessing.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't specific enough. I want that effect but vertically not horizontally. But when i use before with absolute positioning, if my text breaks into two rows, background of :before  just stays at top of the relative (button in this case) element. I want background color to go along with the text.

Comment: @Rob Sorry I was in hurry i thought he can understand the process of my code and accordingly he can fix as per his requirement and thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @LazarRadovanovic you can check it now I fixed as per your requirement

Comment: @internthings Thank you it is, but there is a minor problem at word breaking. I had that same result, background stays at top of the <p> element because of absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understand by your question,
this snippet might gonna be help you.
[Sliced Text Using Background Clip](https://codepen.io/Akshay25/pen/zXjpKw)

```css
.text-grad-1 {
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #ff0000;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff00c3 0%,#ff00c3 50%,#ffffff 52%,#000000 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  margin: 0;
}
.text-grad-2 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #ff0000;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff00c3 0%,#ff00c3 50%,#ffffff 52%,#000000 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.text-grad-2:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    height: 22px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ff00c3;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 32px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.text-grad-3 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #ff0000;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9dd53a 0%,#a1d54f 50%,#80c217 51%,#7cbc0a 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    margin: 0;
}
.text-grad-3:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    height: 27px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #7cbc0a;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -2px;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="text-grad-1">⟵ Sliced Text ⟶</p>
<br/>
<p class="text-grad-2">⟵ Sliced Text ⟶</p>
<br/>
<p class="text-grad-3"> Sliced Text </p>
```

Comment: That is the effect i want, but when paragraph goes into two rows, background-color of :after elements stays at bottom because of absolute positioning.